# How do I solve this? Find determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a matrix with n rows and n columns: $A=(a_{j,k})$ is defined:
$$(a_{j,k})=\begin{cases}
  \begin{split}
    2j (j\neq k) \\ 0(j=k)
  \end{split} \end{cases}$$ 
And I need to find $det(A)$. I think that I need to use gauss elimination but I have no idea how to do this here. can anyone help please? thanks.

Comment: You may start from factoring out $2j$ from each column in the determinant.

Comment: @A.Γ. sorry, I did not write the question well. I needed to write a(j,k) insted of a(k,j) but this is still the same, so now i need to factor 2j from each row. I have done that, and i get a messy matrix with much 1's, i understood that on the diagnole there are 0's and the other are 1's, but how can i calculate the determinant of that matrix?

Comment: If you add the identity matrix to the result, you will get a very nice matrix.

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, I see, I will get a matrix of 1's, and its determinant of this is 0. but, there is no formula for det(A+B) as an expression of detA and detB, nothing that I was tought at least... so how does that help me?

Answer (score 2):

After factoring out $2j$ you will get the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &1&\ldots&1\end{bmatrix}-I=ee^T-I.
$$
Now use the [Sylvester determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity)
$$
\det(ee^T-I)=(-1)^n\det(I-ee^T)=(-1)^n(1-e^Te)=(-1)^n(1-n).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking out the $2j$ factors as suggested leaves $E-I$, with $I$ the identity matrix and $E$ all $1s$. If $a$ has shape $n\times n$ the eigenvalues of $E$ are $0,\,n$, of respective multiplicity $n-1,\,1$. Then $$\det (E-I)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1),\,\det a=-n!(n-1)(-2)^n.$$

Comment: sorry for keep asking stupid questions, but i still did not understand the last part of det(E-I). Is there a way to show this using gauss elimination

Comment: @Omer Which part is unclear: how I get the eigenvalues' multiplicities, how I get the determinant from there, or the scaling to compute $\det a$? If it's the first part, the trick is that $Ev=0$ only places one constraint on an eigenvector, so the eigenspace has dimension $n-1$, while any $\lambda=n$ eigenvector is parallel to the all-$1$s vector.